# strike-through a good indicator for removed values in a list

Tags: tables, lists, css, background, value

Is a strike-through a good indicator for removed values in a list?

Currently, the background of the removed values is red, but we need another grammar indicator to show that the value has been removed between different versions. Is there any convention for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

A red background can also mean "incomplete", "in danger", "disabled but still there", "not connected/available" etc.

Strike-through is usually associated with "this was here but it's gone now", mostly for lists (like a grocery list).

It also keeps it readable without having to read text on a different background color. I personally find black text on red to be annoying to read, and changing the font color to make it more readable can just lead to further confusion.

If you're showing a list with values that are removed, I would use strike-through personally.